# Make c++ program to pass input output to windows command prommpt interactively

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, pipe, ipc

I want to make a simple program that starts a cmd.exe parallely and takes input from the user as a command, which is then passed to the cmd.exe, after execution my program should take the output from cmd.exe and display it to the user. Basically an interface to a command prompt.

I don't want to use methods like system() as they start a new instance of cmd every time and I can't run commands like cd.

I tried it with the following code with which I am able to spawn a cmd and show initial line (copyright....), but passing commands simply returns the same line again.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <process.h>
using namespace std;

DWORD WINAPI exec(LPVOID inputP){

char* input=(char*) inputP;
HANDLE stdinRd, stdinWr, stdoutRd, stdoutWr;
SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa = {sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES), NULL, true};
STARTUPINFO si;
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
DWORD stuff;
char buff[1000];


//Create the main transfer pipe
if(!CreatePipe(&stdinRd, &stdinWr, &sa, 0) || !CreatePipe(&stdoutRd,&stdoutWr, &sa, 0)) {
cout<<"Pipe creation failed"<<endl;
}

//Get Process Startup Info
GetStartupInfo(&si);
si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESTDHANDLES | STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
si.wShowWindow = SW_SHOW;
si.hStdOutput = stdoutWr;
si.hStdError = stdoutWr;                                                                                               
si.hStdInput = stdinRd;

//Create the CMD Shell using the process startup info above

if(!CreateProcess("C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe", NULL, NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi)) {
cout<<"Error Spawning Command Prompt."<<endl;
}


//Main while(1) Loop
while(1) 
{
Sleep(100);
//Check if cmd.exe has not stoped
GetExitCodeProcess(pi.hProcess, &stuff);
//Stop the while loop if not active
if(stuff != STILL_ACTIVE) break;

//Copy Data from buffer to pipe and vise versa
PeekNamedPipe(stdoutRd, NULL, 0, NULL, &stuff, NULL);

ZeroMemory(buff, sizeof(buff));

//Read Console Output
ReadFile(stdoutRd, buff, 1000, &stuff, NULL);
//output 
cout<<buff<<endl;


//Read data from stream and pipe it to cmd.exe
WriteFile(stdinWr, input, strlen(input), &stuff, NULL);

}

return 0;
}
int main() {
while(1){
char a[100];
cin>>a;
CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)exec, (LPVOID)a, 0, NULL);
}
}
```

Comment: The loop in main is calling exec() for every single item the user enters.  That's not what you wanted, is it?  That means you will keep getting new instances of cmd.exe

Comment: Looks like the first problem is that you aren't sending `RETURN`.  The command interpreter is patiently waiting for you to finish entering the command.

Comment: I had tried starting the cmd only once (by putting an if condition to run it only once) but still i am only getting the initial line of the command prompt (microsoft windows version.... then path ...). Can you tell if any better method exists for the same? i checked the task manager the cmd.exe is starting but not sending any response back of the entered cmmand..

Answer (score 0):

Found my problem, was quite silly.  Just need to pass a new line character so that cmd interprets the data as a command, i.e.,

```
cin>>a;
strcat(a,"\n");
```

and obviously make a single instance of cmd by calling the thread only once and passing parameters through global variables.